# Simple C program not calculating correctly

Tags: c, math

So, I'm completely new to programming, and I'm learning to program C. I'm trying to write a simple program in C to calculate commission as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float fRate, fSales_Price, fCost, fCommission;

    printf("\nEnter your commission rate: ");
    scanf("%.2f",&fRate);
    printf("\nEnter the price of the item sold: ");
    scanf("%.2f", &fSales_Price);
    printf("\nEnter the original cost of the item: ");
    scanf("%.2f", &fCost);

    fCommission = (fRate / 100) * (fSales_Price - fCost);

    printf("\nYour commission is: %.2f", fCommission);
}
```

Whenever I try to run it, two things happen. First, if I try to enter any decimals into the program, e.g. if I said the rate was 12.5, it immediately skips the other inputs and completes the program, saying commission is 0.00. If I ignore decimals, the program runs fine until the end, when I still get commission as 0.00. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`"%.2f"` is an illegal format string for `scanf`, so your code causes undefined behaviour.  The correct format string is `"%f"`.

Also you should check the result of scanf. If `scanf` fails, the bad data is not consumed from the input and so subsequent scanfs fail too (this is why you see the other inputs skipped).

For example:

```
if ( 1 != scanf("%f", &fRate) )
{ 
    printf("Invalid input for fRate.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format specifier is wrong, you must use compiler warnings if you do, then you wouldn't be asking this, because that format specifier is invalid, you cannot limit the number of decimal places with `scanf()` it's been discussed in many questions on SO, more importantly you don't need to, and it wouldn't be meaningful, so just remove the `.2` from your format specifier, and instead, check that `scanf()` succeeded before using the values.

Answer (score 1):

`"%.2f"` is not a valid format for `scanf`. See [`scanf()` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for details.

The easiest format to use is `"%f"`.

Also, it's a good practice to check the return value of `scanf` so you know when the operation was successful.

```
if ( scanf("%f", &fRate) != 1 )
{
   // Error reading the data.
   // Deal with the error.
}
```

Comment: That is such a simple error on my part. Thank you for the advice, I'll start trying to do that from now on.